# Different format of querystring

Tags: javascript, php

Generally, We are using querystring to get the detail from the url. I am using the url like:

```
"example.com?q=abc"
```

in php with javascript. I need to use the url like

```
"example.com/abc"
```

Is it possible to use url like this "example.com/abc" ?

Comment: Yes this is possible, but unless you use url rewriting or a routing technique, navigating from '"example.com' to '"example.com/abc"' will trigger a page reload.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the QueryString is what is after the first question mark, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string for example. 
So your second url does not contain a  QueryString. But it does not mean you cannot get the "abc" value with JavaScript: you can get the full url via

```
window.location.href
```

and then you can parse it.